# How to continue Javascript function after Button click with Codebehind method is finished?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Hello I have a `javascript` function which look like this:

```
function WebGrid1_OnAfterAdd(controlId) 
{      
    document.getElementById('TeilnehmerCounterButton').click()    
    var intern = document.getElementById('InterneTeilnehmer').value;
    var extern = document.getElementById('ExterneTeilnehmer').value;
    parent.parentTeilnehmer(intern, extern)
}
```

Only after the `TeilnehmerCounterButton` button with the `codebehind` method is finished it should load rest of the function.
 how can i do this?

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: If you want the `javascript` to run after `code-behind` then try something like this [Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock.aspx)

Comment: isnt there any other solution?`

Comment: May be you have some hidden field in the form and assign value to it from `code-behind` and on page load with javascript check for the assigned value, if it matches then go ahead with your `scripts`.